# how to convert lists to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i wonder to convert 'list to dictionary'.

**input** :

```
G_list = ['BRAF\tGly464Glu', 'BRAF\tGly464Val', 'BRAF\tGly466Glu', 'BRAF\tGly466Val']
```

**wondering output**:

```
{'BRAF' : ['Gly464Glu', 'Gly464Val', 'Gly466Glu', 'Gly466Val']}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
d = {}
for s in G_list:
    k, v = s.split("\t")
    # k, v = s.split("\t", 1)  # if the value might contain more tabs
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Since this is essentially csv data (maybe coming from a file, a `.csv` or rather a `.tsv`), you can also consider using the `csv` module. The `reader` in particular will work on any iterable of strings:

```
from csv import reader

d = {}
for k, v in reader(G_list, delimiter="\t"):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Some docs:

- [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)
- [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Comment: This will create a new list object in each iteration

Comment: Well, an empty one that is immediately discarded (if unused), so it won't affect asymptotic time or space complexity

Answer (score 1):

Split by a whitespace (using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split)) and store the results using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

G_list = ['BRAF\tGly464Glu', 'BRAF\tGly464Val', 'BRAF\tGly466Glu', 'BRAF\tGly466Val']

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in map(str.split, G_list):
    d[key].append(value)
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'BRAF': ['Gly464Glu', 'Gly464Val', 'Gly466Glu', 'Gly466Val']})
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches:

```
from collections import defaultdict
G_list = ['BRAF\tGly464Glu', 'BRAF\tGly464Val', 'BRAF\tGly466Glu', 'BRAF\tGly466Val']
out = defaultdict(list)
for item in G_list:
    data = item.split('\t')
    out[data[0]].append(data[1])
    
print (out)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'BRAF': ['Gly464Glu', 'Gly464Val', 'Gly466Glu', 'Gly466Val']})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
G_list = ['BRAF\tGly464Glu', 'BRAF\tGly464Val', 
'BRAF\tGly466Glu', 'BRAF\tGly466Val']
d={ }
for s in G_list :
     u, v = s.spilt("\t")
     d.setdefault(u, [ ]).append(v)
 Print(d)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

def Convert(lst):

```
res_dct = {lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)}

return res_dct
```

lst = ['BRAF\tGly464Glu', 'BRAF\tGly464Val', 'BRAF\tGly466Glu', 'BRAF\tGly466Val']

print(Convert(lst))